# Does air has surface?

Tags: experimental-physics, fluid-statics, atmospheric-science

> Does air or any gas generally have a surface, like if we spread any has in total vacuum, they should also tend to gather together due to atleast gravitational attractions, if intermolecular forces are negligible, so doesn't that form a surface, and if so does the surface has surface area, will such a volume be spherical?

Comment: The galaxy is not spherical…

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy gas molecules have (and monatomic noble gases) is sufficiently high so that any gravitational attraction they have toward each other is negligible so that any “shape” they have will be random. Furthermore because the earth’s gravitational field will pull the molecules toward the ground, formation of any definite shape is unlikely (but you will find that the atmosphere raps around the earth in a spherical shape).

In space (away from any gravitational field which will affect the motion of the gas molecules) where you can have large volumes of gas molecules (and therefore considerable mass) gravitational forces can cause the formation of planets and stars (note that these are made out of gaseous “plasma”) which indeed are spherical.

Comment: So is it that air also has a surface like the surface of earth's atmosphere?

Comment: Yes, but because the earth is a sphere and holds the air down all around it.